# Vertical Scroll bars in Jekyll Rouge

Tags: jekyll, scrollbars, rouge

Is there anyway to add vertical scroll bars in Jekyll for really long code? I tried adding a Height attribute in _syntax.scss but with no luck. The syntax highlighter I'm using is rouge and the theme I'm using is here: https://github.com/mmistakes/hpstr-jekyll-theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, make sure you add this CSS to your theme:

```
pre.highlight {
  max-height: 200px; /* Change to your desired max height */
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**Update.**
Using the OP URL provided here's what I did:

Lookp where the class highlight is defined and add this to the end of its declaration:

```
.highlight {
  [...]
  border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  background-color: #272822;
  border-radius: 3px;

/** This part **/
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Results:
[image: After new CSS]

Comment: That kinda works if you put it under the pre tag instead of pre.highlight, but it looks funny: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Supercap2F/supercap2f.github.io/master/images/funnycode.png

Comment: Did you put overflow or overflow-y? Looks like overflow to me, unless you have other CSS that interferes. I tried it on the Hpstr theme page directly and it worked fine.

Comment: I put overflow-y just like your code, and I don't think I have any custom css that would effect it. Also I tried putting that code under .highlight and here's how it came out: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Supercap2F/supercap2f.github.io/master/images/funnypic2.png It doesn't have the themes style and doesn't show the bottom scroll bars until you scroll all the way down.

Comment: Cool  if you site is live I could also take a look at the end result. And propose the exact CSS you need.

Comment: That might work!  This is the page: https://supercap2f.github.io/CPU-Power-Supply-Mod/. Scroll all the way down for the code block.

Comment: Updated my answer :)

Comment: Just learning so just asking if instead of `max-height: 300px;` it could be something like `max-height: 80%`? I have 3 different pixel heights on different machines Also I'm thinking 80% of browser window not hardware because 4k monitor browser window might only be 40% high..